# Show that the range of $p(z)e^{q(z)}$ for nonconstant polynomials $p$ and $q$ is all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a question from an old qualifying exam I am trying to solve.

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are nonconstant polynomials. Prove that the range of the function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(z)=p(z)e^{q(z)}$ is all of $\mathbb{C}$.

My assumption is that I will need to use Picard's Little Theorem.  I know that $e^{q(z)}$ omits only $0$ and $p(z)$ has range all of $\mathbb{C}$.  However, I cannot see how to properly use this information. Any hint or suggestion would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you need the big theorem of Picard, the little theorem is not sufficient.

$$f(z) = p(z) e^{q(z)}$$

has an essential singularity in $\infty$ and only finitely many zeros. Now apply Picard's (big) theorem.